# How to exclude a child element from being repeated in an element which carries an ng-repeat directive

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a call log where I need to be able to edit the details of the customer who called. **The update method is working fine** but the form appears for every customer, where I wanted to appear for the specified customer

```
<div ng-repeat= "post in posts">
<h1>post.title</h1>
<h2>post.number<h2>
<button ng-click="isUpdate()">update</button>

<form>
//some input feilds
</form>

</div>
```

I am able to update every customer detail successfully but I only want the form to appear for every single customer at a time. I have tried adding the following to the form element:

```
<form ng-show="post._id">
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the form to appear for specific customers, Try to check the logic to show the form in a function:

```
<form ng-if="showToSpecificCustomers(post._id)">
//some input feilds
</form>
```

Now in your controller:

```
$scope.showToSpecificCustomers = function(postId) {
   // check the customer information here
   // match with postId if required

   // based on the result, return true/false.
}
```

Comment: I believe your code sounds legitimate dear, but however I am not really sure what to add in the $scope.showToSpecificCustomers

Comment: You've shared only limited information @user3651862. Hope the customer information is available in the controller. So inside the showToSpecificCustomers method, check the necessary customer information there to show/hide the form

Comment: Dear I have tried the following so far:

`$scope.showCustomerUpdateFeild = function (post) {
        for(i =0; i < $scope.posts.length; i++ ){
            if(post._id = this.post._id)
            {
                return true
                console.log(post._id)
            }
            else
            {
                return false
            }
        }
    }`

@mohamedrias